Transition or post-feedback after a user action
I’m designing a CRM mobile app where users can convert a lead into an opportunity. Here’s the current flow:

Lead Details Screen: Contains a “Convert to Opportunity” button.
Conversion Form: Users fill in details like opportunity name, stage, and initial deal amount.
Action: After completing the form, the user taps the “Convert Lead,” which adds the lead to the opportunity list.

My challenge is:
What should happen immediately after the user taps “Convert Lead”?
How do I communicate to the user that the conversion was successful and the opportunity is now part of the list?
I want to ensure the user isn’t confused or feels “lost” in the process.
Should the app redirect to the opportunity list, show a confirmation screen, or provide another form of feedback? I’d love input on designing, thank you.


What should happen immediately after the user taps “Convert Lead”?

First, you need to consider the delay in processing the conversion. Most of the time it may be instant, but sometimes it may take a few seconds.
I would suggest that you ensure the button is immediately disabled (so the user cannot click more than once), and show some sort of process animation while the opportunity is created.

Should the app redirect to the opportunity list, show a confirmation screen, or provide another form of feedback?

Once the process in complete, show a confirmation to the user and then give them the choice of what to do next.
The confirmation can just be a simple message, but maybe you also want to include some other information about the result. Such as if a reference number is generated, then include that with the confirmation message.
A simple example:

